# what approach should i follow - swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

[image]

how can i build the same design like this ... please guide me i just want an idea that how i can achieve the same view. i know what is tableview and all but thing is how to populate tableview with three different cell type and there postion is not fixed depend on beckend.

and all cell are clickable (push to another Viewcontroller)

Comment: It just looks like a tableview with 3 sections. There are plenty of tutorials available on UITableView if you haven't worked with them before.

Comment: @Paulw11 but the thing is there are three different types of cell and the position of cell is not fixed

Comment: Still, there are more than enough tutorials on the subject. Here are some hints for you: This is a `grouped` style tableView, returning different types of cells in `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: you are not getting my point , here the cells are not fixed

Comment: Do you mean the location of he various cell groups are not fixed?  You need to explain your problem more clearly. If you are talking about layout, you need to determine the layout requirements and write the code.

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide diff cells (does't matter if in different sections or only a single one) all you need to do is to register multiple different "prototypes" of cells (each with diff layout/style/etc.) with the table view. You can then use your "business logic" to dequeue (if reusable) specific "type" as you need.

to register a prototype cell programatically use

```
func register(_ cellClass: AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

if you use storyboard - you can simply drags multiple cells into the tableview

then in the

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

you dequeue the right cell type

```
func dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier identifier: String) -> UITableViewCell?
```

cell is "selectable" by utilising the tableview's delegate method

```
optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

Answer (score -1):

In order to create this view the easiest way from my side is
Create a simple collection view with different sections and in each section, multiple rows will be there

Here you check the screenshot of demoapp :
http://prntscr.com/lioqjz

Where section and rows both are dynamic

To do this view we are using UICollectionreusableview to give space between each sections using as footer view, Here is the code of collectionview implementation:

```
extension ViewController:UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {


func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
 //If you have different rows with different sections then you follow through array count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath) as! customCollectionViewCell

    cell.txtLabel.text="Type="+String(indexPath.section)+""+String(indexPath.row)
    return cell
}

}
```

and here is the SS of storyboard:
http://prntscr.com/liosvm

And to cell use to clickable, you can add UITapgesture in each cell

Comment: the exact view i want to build is this [link](https://prnt.sc/lipmru)  [link 2](https://prnt.sc/lipnnp)

Comment: Okay i will update my answer,first check this ss and tell me the exact requirement
http://prntscr.com/liq62g

Comment: imageView is not required